# How to tell if parent transaction is joinable in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can see that I am inside a transaction by using `class.connection.transaction_open?` but what I'm trying to find out is if that transaction set `joinable: false`. Is there a way to do this? I could not find a way to actually get the Transaction object to check the value of `@joinable`

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution, needed to use `class.connection.current_transaction.joinable?`